# Trying to solve a Pinescript syntax error

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I keep receiving this error in Pine script and it can't get rid of it:

> Error at 5:18 Syntax error at input '['

```
//@version=5
indicator("Vertical Line Indicator", overlay=true)

// Define the symbols and dates
symbolDateList = [
    ["MVIS", timestamp("2023-06-01 00:00")],
    ["XAUUSD", timestamp("2023-06-03 00:00")]
]

// Plot vertical lines
for symbolDate in symbolDateList
    if syminfo.tickerid == symbolDate[0] and time == symbolDate[1]
        line.new(bar_index, low, bar_index, high, color=color.rgb(0, 191, 255), width=1)
```

As you can see I'm trying to get a vertical line for each specific symbol and specific date.

If I use this code:

```
//@version=5
indicator("Vertical Line Indicator", overlay=true)

// Define the symbols and dates
symbolDateList = array([
    ["MVIS", timestamp("2023-06-01 00:00")],
    ["XAUUSD", timestamp("2023-06-03 00:00")]
])

// Plot vertical lines
for symbolDate in symbolDateList
    if syminfo.tickerid == symbolDate[0] and time == symbolDate[1]
        line.new(x1=bar_index, y1=low, x2=bar_index, y2=high, color=color.rgb(0, 191, 255), width=2, style=line.style_solid)
```

I receive the following error message:

> Error at 5:25 Syntax error at input 'end of line without line continuation'

Answer (score 0):

In Pinescript, you can't address array or a matrix like this.

To define a matrix, you should use :
`matrix.new<type>(rows, columns, initial_value)`
See : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_matrix.new%3Ctype%3E

To read a value in the matrix, you should use :
`matrix.get(id, row, column)`
See : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_matrix.get

To set a value in the matrix, you should use :
`matrix.set(id, row, column, value)`
See : https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_matrix.set

Comment: Thanks G.Lebret for your quick reply. Because i'm not a programmer and trying to program using chatgpt i don't really understand the solutions you provided and if its gonna work like i want to. What i want to achieve is that a vertical line appears if the symbol and the date matches the symbol and date in the script

Comment: @EricZ just use the links in my answer and you will be able to work with matrix.